# Scraping a website for multiple pages that url does not c

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using `beautifulSoup` and `Selenium` to extract the company names and the ratings from this website: https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-ratings. However, the url does not change when I click to a following page and the link in hrefcurrent of page is not available. Has anyone has any idea how I should do this? this is my code to extract the first page now and it works well:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

#%%%
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
  # Run Chrome in headless mode

# Specify the path to the ChromeDriver executable
webdriver_service = Service('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')

# Choose Chrome browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

# URL of the website
url = "https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-ratings"

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

htlm_content = driver.page_source
# Close the browser
driver.quit()

#%%
# Open the webpage
soup = bs(htlm_content, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
esg_ratings = soup.find('div',class_='col-md-8')
#print(esg_ratings)
#%%
company_names = []
ratings = []
company_rows = soup.find_all(class_='company-row')
#%%
for company_row in company_rows:
    company_name_elem = company_row.find(class_='primary-color')
    if company_name_elem is not None:
        company_name = company_name_elem.get_text()
    esg_risk_rating_elem = company_row.find(class_='col-2')
    if esg_risk_rating_elem is not None:
        esg_risk_rating = esg_risk_rating_elem.get_text()
    company_names.append(company_names)
    ratings.append(ratings)
    print(f"Company: {company_name}")
    print(f"Rating: {esg_risk_rating}")
```

Many thanks!

I have tried multiple suggestions but none work

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use their pagination Ajax API:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.sustainalytics.com/sustapi/companyratings/getcompanyratings'

data =     {
    "industry": "",
    "rating": "",
    "filter": "",
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": "10",
    "resourcePackage": "Sustainalytics"
}

for data['page'] in range(1, 5):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(url, data=data).content, 'html.parser')
    for company in soup.select('.company-row'):
        name = company.a.text
        score = company.select_one('.col-2').text
        print(f'{name:<70} {score}')
```

Prints:

```
1-800-FLOWERS.COM, Inc.                                                23.6
1&1 AG                                                                 22.2
10X Genomics, Inc.                                                     22.6
11 Bit Studios SA                                                      16.3
1Life Healthcare, Inc.                                                 22.5
1st Source Corp.                                                       31.7
1stdibs.com, Inc.                                                      26.7
22nd Century Group, Inc.                                               35.4
23andMe Holding Co.                                                    25.6
29metals Ltd.                                                          42.8
2i Rete Gas SpA                                                        25.2

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this to click on the next pages on the mentioned website:

```
# click and process the next pages
for i in range(2, page_num+1):
    driver.execute_script(f"""
    function getElementByXpath(path) {{
       return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    }};
    getElementByXpath('//*[@id="victor-pagination"]/a[@class="pagination-page" and text()="{i}"]').click();
    """)
```

The complete solution:

```py
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

driver = Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
url = "https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-ratings"
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a#hs-eu-confirmation-button'))).click()

data = []

def data_processing(source):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
    selected_page = soup.select_one('span.pagination-page.selected').text
    print(f"---------------------- This is page {selected_page} ----------------------")

    container = soup.select_one('section#company_ratings')
    company_rows = container.find_all(class_='company-row')

    for company_row in company_rows:
        company_name = company_row.find(class_='primary-color').get_text()
        esg_risk_rating = company_row.find(class_='col-2').get_text()

        print(f"Company: {company_name} | Rating: {esg_risk_rating}")
        data.append({"Company": company_name, "Rating": esg_risk_rating})

def first_page():
    # process the 1st page
    data_processing(driver.page_source)
    return f"data:\n{data}"

def multiple_page(page_num):
    # process the first page
    data_processing(driver.page_source)

    # click and process next pages
    for i in range(2, page_num+1):
        driver.execute_script(f"""
        function getElementByXpath(path) {{
           return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
        }};
        getElementByXpath('//*[@id="victor-pagination"]/a[@class="pagination-page" and text()="{i}"]').click();
        """)

        time.sleep(2)
        data_processing(driver.page_source)

    return f"data:\n{data}"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # print(first_page())
    print(multiple_page(4))
```

output:

```
---------------------- This is page 1 ----------------------
Company: 1-800-FLOWERS.COM, Inc. | Rating: 23.6
Company: 1&1 AG | Rating: 22.2
Company: 10X Genomics, Inc. | Rating: 22.6
Company: 11 Bit Studios SA | Rating: 16.3
Company: 1Life Healthcare, Inc. | Rating: 22.5
Company: 1st Source Corp. | Rating: 31.7
Company: 1stdibs.com, Inc. | Rating: 26.7
Company: 22nd Century Group, Inc. | Rating: 35.4
Company: 23andMe Holding Co. | Rating: 25.6
Company: 29metals Ltd. | Rating: 42.8
---------------------- This is page 2 ----------------------
Company: 2i Rete Gas SpA | Rating: 25.2
Company: 2seventy Bio, Inc. | Rating: 32.0
Company: 2U, Inc. | Rating: 26.8
Company: 360 DigiTech, Inc. | Rating: 28.4
Company: 360 One Wam Ltd. | Rating: 33.3
Company: 360 Security Technology, Inc. | Rating: 23.1
Company: 361 Degrees International Ltd. | Rating: 18.6
Company: 37 Interactive Entertainment Network Technology Group Co. Ltd. | Rating: 14.3
Company: 3D Systems Corp. | Rating: 23.0
Company: 3i Group Plc | Rating: 11.1
---------------------- This is page 3 ----------------------
Company: 3M Co. | Rating: 33.9
Company: 3M India Ltd. | Rating: 23.4
Company: 3R Petroleum Óleo e Gás SA | Rating: 56.7
Company: 3SBio, Inc. | Rating: 27.1
Company: 407 East Development Group GP | Rating: 45.7
Company: 407 International, Inc. | Rating: 11.4
Company: 4D Molecular Therapeutics, Inc. | Rating: 28.4
Company: 4imprint Group Plc | Rating: 17.2
Company: 5E Advanced Materials, Inc. | Rating: 42.0
Company: 5I5J Holding Group Co. Ltd. | Rating: 15.0
---------------------- This is page 4 ----------------------
Company: 7-Eleven Malaysia Holdings Bhd. | Rating: 24.6
Company: 7-Eleven, Inc. | Rating: 35.1
Company: 888 Holdings Plc | Rating: 18.7
Company: 8x8, Inc. | Rating: 29.9
Company: 908 Devices, Inc. | Rating: 36.8
Company: 91APP, Inc. | Rating: 25.8
Company: A-Living Smart City Services Co., Ltd. | Rating: 9.3
Company: A-Mark Precious Metals, Inc. | Rating: 30.3
Company: A. O. Smith Corp. | Rating: 25.4
Company: A.G. BARR Plc | Rating: 23.7
data:
[{'Company': '1-800-FLOWERS.COM, Inc.', 'Rating': '23.6'}, {'Company': '1&1 AG', 'Rating': '22.2'}, {'Company': '10X Genomics, Inc.', 'Rating': '22.6'}, {'Company': '11 Bit Studios SA', 'Rating': '16.3'}, {'Company': '1Life Healthcare, Inc.', 'Rating': '22.5'}, {'Company': '1st Source Corp.', 'Rating': '31.7'}, {'Company': '1stdibs.com, Inc.', 'Rating': '26.7'}, {'Company': '22nd Century Group, Inc.', 'Rating': '35.4'}, {'Company': '23andMe Holding Co.', 'Rating': '25.6'}, {'Company': '29metals Ltd.', 'Rating': '42.8'}, {'Company': '2i Rete Gas SpA', 'Rating': '25.2'}, {'Company': '2seventy Bio, Inc.', 'Rating': '32.0'}, {'Company': '2U, Inc.', 'Rating': '26.8'}, {'Company': '360 DigiTech, Inc.', 'Rating': '28.4'}, {'Company': '360 One Wam Ltd.', 'Rating': '33.3'}, {'Company': '360 Security Technology, Inc.', 'Rating': '23.1'}, {'Company': '361 Degrees International Ltd.', 'Rating': '18.6'}, {'Company': '37 Interactive Entertainment Network Technology Group Co. Ltd.', 'Rating': '14.3'}, {'Company': '3D Systems Corp.', 'Rating': '23.0'}, {'Company': '3i Group Plc', 'Rating': '11.1'}, {'Company': '3M Co.', 'Rating': '33.9'}, {'Company': '3M India Ltd.', 'Rating': '23.4'}, {'Company': '3R Petroleum Óleo e Gás SA', 'Rating': '56.7'}, {'Company': '3SBio, Inc.', 'Rating': '27.1'}, {'Company': '407 East Development Group GP', 'Rating': '45.7'}, {'Company': '407 International, Inc.', 'Rating': '11.4'}, {'Company': '4D Molecular Therapeutics, Inc.', 'Rating': '28.4'}, {'Company': '4imprint Group Plc', 'Rating': '17.2'}, {'Company': '5E Advanced Materials, Inc.', 'Rating': '42.0'}, {'Company': '5I5J Holding Group Co. Ltd.', 'Rating': '15.0'}, {'Company': '7-Eleven Malaysia Holdings Bhd.', 'Rating': '24.6'}, {'Company': '7-Eleven, Inc.', 'Rating': '35.1'}, {'Company': '888 Holdings Plc', 'Rating': '18.7'}, {'Company': '8x8, Inc.', 'Rating': '29.9'}, {'Company': '908 Devices, Inc.', 'Rating': '36.8'}, {'Company': '91APP, Inc.', 'Rating': '25.8'}, {'Company': 'A-Living Smart City Services Co., Ltd.', 'Rating': '9.3'}, {'Company': 'A-Mark Precious Metals, Inc.', 'Rating': '30.3'}, {'Company': 'A. O. Smith Corp.', 'Rating': '25.4'}, {'Company': 'A.G. BARR Plc', 'Rating': '23.7'}]
```